# ¿Como condicionar correctamente las coordenadas de un elemento HTML con mousemove en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Lo que necesito en concreto es obtener las coordenadas de un `div` para poder condicionarlas (correctamente), como por ejemplo con evento nuevo. Ahora.. el problema es que ya lo tengo resuelto hasta ese punto, la cuestión es que a la hora de ejecutar el evento "hijo" por llamarlo de alguna manera, este se vuelve bucle, a continuación dejo un código explicado de ejemplo.

Para aclarar, esto con el fin de afectar al objeto hermano que hay debajo un `div` si necesidad de afectar las transiciones o efectos del mismo. Ya que por ejemplo, si colocase el `p` como hijo del `div` y quisiera ponerle un efecto `fadeIn/Out()` en toggle a este ultimo, y paso el mouse sobre el párrafo se produce un efecto extraño que no es deseado, también si hay otra manera de hacer esto, es bienvenida.

La librearía de cookie-js te permite facilitar el trabajo con cookies. Es bastante intuitivo y aunque esta incluida en el código, la parte donde guardo la cookie esta comentada para no causar problemas en la pagina, pero así se dan una mejor idea del problema.

```js
function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    $("#coor").html(coor);
    $(".heart").on("click",function() {

      if (x < 68 && x > 34 && y < 55 && y > 49 ) {

        $("#pcontain").css({"color":"rgb(191, 90, 136)"});
        $("#pcontain").css({"background-color":"white"});
        /*var cookie = Cookies.get("suma");
          var checkcookie = isNaN(cookie)
          if (checkcookie == true) {

            cookie = 0;

          }
          console.log(cookie);
          cookie = parseInt(cookie);
          var numero = 1;
          var suma = cookie + numero;
          Cookies.set("suma", suma);
          $('#likes').html(cookie);*/

      }else{
      
        $("#pcontain").css({"color":"black"});
        $("#pcontain").css({"background-color":"transparent"});
      
      }


    });

}

function clearCoor() {
    $("#coor").html("");
}
```

```css
* {

  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

#maindiv {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
 
}

#maindiv p {

  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;


}

.heart {

  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <div id = "maindiv">
 
   <div onmousemove="showCoords(event)" onmouseout="clearCoor()" class="heart">

        </div>
        <p id="pcontain"><i class="fal fa-heart">Hola</i></p>
 
 </div>
 <p style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(191, 90, 136);">Haz click en Hola!</p>
 <p style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(191, 90, 136);">Haz click luego fuera de Hola!</p>
 <p id="coor"></p>
```

> El problema esta aquí.

```
$(".heart").on("click",function() {

      if (x < 68 && x > 34 && y < 55 && y > 49 ) {...}
```

Cuando se ejecuta la función `click()` se crea un bucle en el código que hace que se ejecute indefinidas veces (aunque parece multiplicarse) hasta que se detiene, como mencione antes no puedo almacenar las cookies en Stack, por lo que dejo el print de mi consola (en este caso se ejecuto 30 veces).

[image: Consola]

Y también se pueden dar cuenta de que esto pasa ya que al hacer clic en mi ejemplo puedes notar una especie de dalay y/o crash al cambiar los colores.

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa? Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El delay es porque le estas asignando el evento click múltiples veces (en cada movimiento del mouse), prueba con:

```
$(".heart").off('click').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Eres lo mejor, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Y bueno, intuí que era por eso pero no conocía `off()`, intente hacerlo hasta con `Event.stopPropagation()`, nuevamente gracias.

Comment: tal vez convenga tener una variable global ( por ej `estoyPasandoo`) que se actualiza en cada movimiento indicando si está dentro del elemento, y el click también por fuera que hace cosas sólo si esa variable es `true`. sería un poco mas óptimo que estar enganchando y desenganchando el evento.